# Fetching Data From Server Database to Sqlite Database in Android

Tags: php, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am developing an application which contains data stores in a server side SQL database . but the app need to work also in the offline mode so The application have to fetch the data from the server side once it is connected to the internet and have to store that data into an SQLite database . Can any one provide me with the code snippets or any links which contains a good working example. Thank you

Comment: read `android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter` docs

Answer (score 0):

first you have to check are you connected with internet by this code:

```
public static boolean isNetConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

if it returns true then show data from service and store into DB else show from DB.and for insertion or updation you can use

```
 String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + Databaseconnector.TABLE_LOCAL_ROSTER
                + "(UNIQUE_ID,USER_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER,ROLE,PROFILE_NAME,IMAGE,URL,RANK) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

enjoy code:)